# Skip decorator on testing endpoints in FastAPI

Tags: python, unit-testing, fastapi, decorator

I have a decorator for authentication used for my API endpoints in my FastAPI app.

```
@app.get("/foo")
@Authentication.authenticate
async def bar(request: Request):
    return {"message": "Authenticated user"}
```

Now I want to write unit tests for each endpoint, but I prefer to just skip the authentication decorator instead of trying to mock it. I know how to skip the decorator if I want to just test the function itself using `__wraped__` per decorator:

```
def test_bar():
    response = bar.__wrapped__()
    assert response.status == 200
```

But I need to test the endpoint using `TestClient` and wrapping the decorator doesn't work like that:

```
def test_foo():
    response = client.get.__wrapped__("/foo") # => AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__wrapped__'
    assert response.status == 200
```

So what's the right way to skip the decorators while testing the emdpoints?

Comment: An option would be to check, within your `authenticate` method an environment variable that would unplug your authentication mechanism.

Comment: I also recommend using FastAPI's built-in dependency system to handle this instead of decorators; you can override those on a per-test basis.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, I know how dependencies work, and how good overriding them work in tests. but for some reasons I need to use decorators

Comment: In that case we've usually used an environment variable to adjust the behavior of the internal logic as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: You also probably want to look at the `bar` function to be able to find the wrapped function - not the `get` function inside the test client (which is used to resolve the request and forward it to the app). It's also important to remember that `__wrapped__` is provided by `functools.wraps` and not a general property set by Python for all decorated functions.